# How to upload multiple android archives (one for each flavor)

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to upload multiple artifacts per project w/ the maven gradle plugin:

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html

```
53.6.4.1. Multiple artifacts per project

Maven can only deal with one artifact per project. This is reflected in the structure of the Maven POM. We think there are many situations where it makes sense to have more than one artifact per project. In such a case you need to generate multiple POMs. In such a case you have to explicitly declare each artifact you want to publish to a Maven repository. The MavenDeployer and the MavenInstaller both provide an API for this:

Example 53.9. Generation of multiple poms

build.gradle
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://localhost/tmp/myRepo/")
            addFilter('api') {artifact, file ->
                artifact.name == 'api'
            }
            addFilter('service') {artifact, file ->
                artifact.name == 'service'
            }
            pom('api').version = 'mySpecialMavenVersion'
        }
    }
}
You need to declare a filter for each artifact you want to publish. This filter defines a boolean expression for which Gradle artifact it accepts. Each filter has a POM associated with it which you can configure. To learn more about this have a look at PomFilterContainer and its associated classes.
```

Really what I am trying to do is to upload different archives for different flavors of my build.

Here is my projects build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group 'com.test'
version '0.0.1'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 { }
        flavor2 { }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://${System.properties['user.home']}/.m2/repository")

            addFilter('debugFlavor1') { artifact, file ->
                artifact.name.contains("debugFlavor1")
            }
            addFilter('releaseFlavor1') { artifact, file ->
                artifact.name.contains("releaseFlavor1")
            }
            addFilter('debugFlavor2') { artifact, file ->
                artifact.name.contains("debugFlavor2")
            }
            addFilter('releaseFlavor2') { artifact, file ->
                artifact.name.contains("releaseFlavor2")
            }

            pom('debug').artifactId = ${artifactId} + "-" ${flavor} + "-debug"
            pom('release').artifactId = ${artifactId} + "-" ${flavor}
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
}
```

Is something like this possible?

How do I get at the artifactId and flavor in each publish?  I used ${artifactId} and ${flavor} as placeholders but I know that is not right.

**EDIT:**

Alright I figured out how to get a different artifact for each flavor.  One of the keys was to set the:

```
publishNonDefault true
```

However when I do that I do not get a pom file for each artifact.  I have transitive dependencies that need to be pulled in and I don't think they will get pulled in without a pom.

Here is my current gradle script, how do I get a pom generated for each.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group 'com.test'
version '0.0.1'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"
    publishNonDefault true

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {}
        flavor2 {}
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://${System.properties['user.home']}/.m2/repository")

            addFilter('flavor1Release') { artifact, file ->
                artifact.attributes.classifier.equals("flavor1Release")
            }
            addFilter('flavor2Release') { artifact, file ->
                artifact.attributes.classifier.equals("flavor2Release")
            }

            pom('flavor1Release').artifactId = project.archivesBaseName + "-flavor1"
            pom('flavor2Release').artifactId = project.archivesBaseName + "-flavor2";
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem... :(

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: Really fighting maven repo by trying to do this. I tried ivy repo but gradle won't build default and non default artifacts at the same time. I reworked project to have just one SDK and put flavors in app the depends on sdk.

Comment: This is working for me. It actually upload 2 artifacts. Its nice. But artifact file names include additional flavor suffix in it which breaks gradle.

Answer (score 1):

// I have tried the following way and was able to upload multiple jar files.
// hope this help out....

```
import org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.publish.DefaultPublishArtifact

// jarfilename1 and jarfilename2 are the two files that gets upload
// make sure the artifactID and the file name are the same


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'


artifacts{
    archives new DefaultPublishArtifact("jarfileName1", "jar", "jar", null, new Date(), new File("build/", "jarfilename1.jar"))
    archives new DefaultPublishArtifact("jarfileName2", "jar", "jar", null, new Date(), new File("build/", "jarfilename2.jar"))
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
        repository(url: "$archivaUrl") {
        authentication(userName: "$userName", password: "$passWord")
        }

        // addfilter for multiple pom upload 
        addFilter("jarfileName1") {artifact, file ->
                      artifact.name == "jarfileName1"
                     }
        addFilter("jarfileName2") {artifact, file ->
                       artifact.name == "jarfileName2"
                      }

        //Creating pom files and adding the Entity
        pom("jarfileName1").version ='1.1.1'
        pom("jarfileName1").groupId ='what.so.ever'
        pom("jarfileName1").artifactId ='jarfilename1'

        pom("jarfileName2").version ='1.1.1'
        pom("jarfileName2").groupId ='what.so.ever'
        pom("jarfileName2").artifactId ='jarfilename2'
    }
    }
}
```