# Gradle reference to external archive directly

Tags: android, maven, gradle, aar, android-productflavors

How can we refer an archive file ( aar for android or jar in general) from the build.gradle.
   eg : compile files('https://--artifactoryonline.com-url--Debug.aar')

Background/Root Cause :
Android Library project has multiple flavors to be supported.

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        // Add any falvor1 flavor specific details here
    }
   flavor2 {
        // Add any flavor2 specific details here
    }
}
```

While the flavors are working fine and aar is generated and uploaded to the articfactory, reference from the maven is not getting resolved as POM files are not generated for library flavors. which in turn leads to maven-metadata.xml not being updated.

This seems to be an issue - Reference :[How to upload multiple android archives (one for each flavor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160087/how-to-upload-multiple-android-archives-one-for-each-flavor)

So to circumvent the situation wanted to get the archive files as they are generated correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possibly linked to this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331713/publishing-android-library-aar-to-bintray-with-flavors