# Upload archive for a library with flavors with gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I'm developing an SDK with multiple libraries and an example app to show how to use it. The libraries are uploaded in a local maven repo that the app uses to import them.
Everything works fine until I try to use different flavors for one of the libraries (and for the app). 
When I have flavors, the `uploadArchive` task does not show any error but the library is not uploaded. All the other libraries are uploaded successfully.

I have found this: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/pom-files-for-multi-flavored-android-lib-not-published-on-uploadarchives-task/898
It is an old post but it does not have any answer.

Is it possible to upload one of the flavors of a library?
This is my `archive.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply from: "../maven-repo.gradle"

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            def folder = "file://localhost" + myMavenRepoDir()
            repository(url: folder)

            pom.groupId = GROUP
            pom.artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
            pom.version = VERSION_NAME

            pom.project {
                name POM_NAME
                packaging POM_PACKAGING
                description POM_DESCRIPTION
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly check this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331713/publishing-android-library-aar-to-bintray-with-chosen-flavors